# Alexa voice with Jovo Framework: Is this possible to get IntentName by utterance? How can I decide which intent to jump to based on user utterance?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, jovo-framework

I have built an Alexa skill with the following flow:

`LAUNCH -> AccountLinkingIntent -> CampaignIntent`

In `AccountLinkingIntent`, presently I am routing to `CampaignIntent` if Account is already linked.

Up to this everything is working fine. Now I have to add another Intent `ActiveContactIntent` so that the flow becomes:

`LAUNCH -> AccountLinkingIntent -> CampaignIntent / ActiveContactIntent`
i.e, From `AccountLinking` I need to decide which Intent to route to.

The invocation goes like this (CampaignIntent):

```
Alexa, ask <invocation_name> to get my latest campaign result
```

OR (ActiveContactIntent)

```
Alexa, ask <invocation_name> who is my most active contact
```

Based on the utterance, I need to tell Alexa where to go. So far I have the following in `AccountLinkingIntent`

...
return this.toIntent("CampaignIntent");
...

But now I need to decide the same as this:

```
...
if( ... ) {
   return this.toIntent("CampaignIntent");
} else {
   return this.toIntent("ActiveContactIntent");
}
...
```

Is there any way to get the `IntentName` by the utterance so that I can check by the same such as:

```
...
if( intent_name_by_utterance === "CampaignIntent" ) {
   return this.toIntent("CampaignIntent");
} else {
   return this.toIntent("ActiveContactIntent");
}
...
```

Or probably, if it is possible to get `intent_name_by_utterance` I may also pass the value as the argument of `toIntent` method if it is allowed to pass a variable!

```
return this.toIntent(intent_name_by_utterance);
```

**UPDATE:**

I have tried the following to see whether the intent name is being returned:

LAUNCH() {
  return this.toIntent("LinkAccountIntent");
},

async LinkAccountIntent() {
  const intent_name = this.$request.getIntentName();
  this.tell(`Current intent is: ${intent_name}`);
},

Invoked the skill in following two fashions:

```
Alexa, ask <invocation-name> to give me my latest campaign results

Alexa, ask <invocation-name> who is my most active contact
```

`give me my latest campaign results` AND `who is my most active contact` are the utterances for respective intents.

I am using Alexa Test console for testing. In both cases, I was expecting the name of the intent (`this.$request.getIntentName()`), ending up with

> Hmm, I don't know that one.

My intention is to call an intent by its utterance directly by waking up the skill using its invocation name.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should treat both intends separately and not through the launch, because for example in the case

> "Alexa, ask  who is my most active contact"

Alexa skips the `launch` and jumps directly to resolve the intend `ActiveContactIntent`. 
So just as you have the `LAUNCH(){}` function you must also have `CampaignIntent(){}` and `ActiveContactIntent(){}`.
That way you will avoid Alexa answering

> Hmm, I don't know that one.

To verify that the user has already linked his account, you would have to enter a code like the one below:

```
if (!this.$request.getAccessToken()) {
        this.$alexaSkill.showAccountLinkingCard();
        this.tell('Please link you Account');
    } else {
        //code for your respective action
    }
```

I recommend you to check the documentation about "routing with jovo" to have a little more clarity about this topic. You can review it at the following link:
https://www.jovo.tech/docs/routing